# login api with email, password or mobile number,password in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, api, codeigniter-3

I am trying to create an api which enables login for email id and password or mobile number and password in codeigniter but i was unable to do both i don't know the error. Here is my code of controller

Controller code

```
 public function signin()
 {
    $this->default_file();
    $responseData = array();
    if(!empty($_POST['username']))
    {
        $userData = array();
        $get_number = $this->validate_mobile($_POST['username']);
        if(!empty($get_number))
        {
            $userData['usermob'] = $_POST['username'];
        }
        else
        {
            $userData['useremail'] = $_POST['username'];
        }
        $userData['userpass'] = $_POST['userpass'];
        $userSignIn = $this->apm->signin($userData);

        if((((!empty($userSignIn['id'])) && (!empty($userSignIn['useremail']))) ||((!empty($userSignIn['id'])) && (!empty($userSignIn['usermob'])))))
        {
            $session_data = array('id'=> $userSignIn['id'], 'logged_in'=> true);
            $this->session->set_userdata('userLoggedIn', $session_data);
            $userDetails = array();
            $userDetails['id'] = $userSignIn['id'];
            $getUserDetails = $this->apm->getUserDetails($userDetails);

            $responseData['id'] = $getUserDetails['result']['u_id'];
            $responseData['username'] = $getUserDetails['result']['username'];
            $responseData['useremail'] = $getUserDetails['result']['useremail'];
            $responseData['usermob'] = $getUserDetails['result']['usermob'];
            $responseData['userlocation'] = $getUserDetails['result']['userlocation'];
            $responseData['device_token'] = $getUserDetails['result']['device_token'];
            $responseData['device_name'] = $getUserDetails['result']['device_name'];

            $responseArray = array(
                'apiName' => 'signin',
                'version' => '1.0.0',
                'responseCode' => 200,
                'responseMessage' => 'logged in successfully',
                'responseData' => $responseData
            );
        }
        else
        {
            $responseArray = array(
                'apiName' => 'signin',
                'version' => '1.0.0',
                'responseCode' => 204,
                'responseMessage' => "Email or Passwor is incorrect.",
                'responseData' => null//$responseData
            );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $responseArray = array(
            'apiName' => 'signin',
            'version' => '1.0.0',
            'responseCode' => 204,
            'responseMessage' => "Sorry, please provide your input details.",
            'responseData' => null//$responseData
        );
    }
    echo json_encode($responseArray);
    die();
 }

 My modal Code is here
  
  public function signin($userData)
  {
    $arrData = array();
    if(!empty($userData['useremail']) || !empty($userData['usermob']))
    {
        if(!empty($userData['useremail']))
        {
            $where = "useremail='".$userData['useremail']."'";
        }
        if(!empty($userData['usermob']))
        {
            $where = "usermob='".$userData['usermob']."'";
        }
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->where($where);
        $result  = $this->db->get()->result_array();
        if(!empty($result))
        {
            if(!empty($userData['useremail']))
            {
                if(($userData['useremail']) && ($userData['userpass']))
                {
                    $where = "useremail='".$userData['useremail']."' AND userpass='".$userData['userpass']."'";
                    $this->db->select('*');
                    $this->db->from('users');
                    $this->db->where($where);
                    $res = $this->db->get()->result_array();
                    if(!empty($res))
                    {
                        $arrData['id'] = $res[0]['u_id'];
                        $arrData['useremail'] = $res[0]['useremail'];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $arrData['errorLogin'] = 'Incorrect email or password';
                    }
                }
            }

            if(!empty($userData['usermob']))
            {
                if(($userData['usermob']) && ($userData['userpass']))
                {
                    $where = "usermob='".$userData['usermob']."' AND userpass='".$userData['userpass']."'";
                    $this->db->select('*');
                    $this->db->from('users');
                    $this->db->where($where);
                    $res = $this->db->get()->result_array();
                    if(!empty($res))
                    {
                        $arrData['id'] = $res[0]['u_id'];
                        $arrData['usermob'] = $res[0]['usermob'];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $arrData['errorLogin'] = 'Incorrect email or password';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $arrData['error'] = 'Please Enter username and password';
        }
    }
    return $arrData;
  }
```

I was trying to login with email and mobile number but my code gives only one access either with email or with mobile. i want help so that i can login with email and mobile number both.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this code using Postman, hope it can help:

```
    public function signin($userData)
    {
        //get the data using useremail and userpass
        $this->db->where('useremail', $userData['useremail']);
        $this->db->where('userpass', $userData['userpass']);
        $result = $this->db->get('users')->result_array();

        //if there's no result, get the data using usermob and userpass
        if (!$result) {
            $this->db->where('usermob', $userData['usermob']);
            $this->db->where('userpass', $userData['userpass']);
            $result = $this->db->get('users')->result_array();
        }

        //if there's still no result, the username or password was incorect
        if (!$result) {
        $result = 'Wrong Username or Password';
        }

        return $result;
    }
```